# Magento inventory management

Tags: magento

I have to implement a module which will have a buy and sale facility in Magento. I mean a customer can buy as well as sell items at the store.

So, any idea regarding how the product inventory can be managed? Does magento provide such a facility so that we can implement both buy and sale modules and manage their product inventory simultaneously?

Comment: No, magento not provide such type of facility

Comment: okay thanks for the reply. I guess now i have implement these module independently.

Answer (score 0):

Bright Pearl is what you are looking for.

Comment: What exactly this Bright pearl offers in terms of inventory management?